# ¿Cómo convertir un String a IA5STRING?

Tags: php, codificación

¿Hay alguna manera de convertir un string que me llega, en principio en UTF8 a la codificación IA5STRING con php?

El string sería una cosa similar a éste: `ünexample.com`

El carácter problemático es el de la ü, que todo el rato da error debido a que espera un ia5string.

Con el resto de caracteres (aeiou) sin tilde, diéresis o ñ funcionan sin problemas.

Realmente lo único que necesito saber es si hay alguna manera de convertir este carácter ü a IA5STRING y cómo.

(Tiene que acabar luego todo en ASN.1)

Comment: Por favor, estamos en la comunidad en castellano, la parte en inglés no es necesaria (la elimino).

Comment: Hola Carlos Coloma. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Puedes añadir lo que has intentado y por que te ha fallado? Mira [ask] para aprender a hacer mejores preguntas.  Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

IA5STRING es un tipo de cadena de caracteres restringido en la notación ASN.1 y se utiliza para representar los caracteres ISO 646 (IA5).

Aquí puedes encontrar una lista de los caracteres que se pueden representar:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646 (más abajo te dejo la tabla)

Viendo la tabla veras que no existe el caracter `ü` por lo que no es posible representarlo en IA5STRING.

Podrías sin embargo reemplazar o eliminar los caracteres que no te interesen asumiendo que perderás la integridad de los caracteres reemplazos.

Una función que te puede servir puede ser esta:

```
function removeSymbols($string){

$string = trim($string);

$string = str_replace(
    array('á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'ª', 'Á', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä'),
    array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë'),
    array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('í', 'ì', 'ï', 'î', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î'),
    array('i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ô'),
    array('o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ú', 'ù', 'ü', 'û', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü'),
    array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ñ', 'Ñ', 'ç', 'Ç'),
    array('n', 'N', 'c', 'C',),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array("\\", "¨", "º", "-", "~",
         "#", "@", "|", "!", "\"",
         "·", "$", "%", "&", "/",
         "(", ")", "?", "'", "¡",
         "¿", "[", "^", "<code>", "]",
         "+", "}", "{", "¨", "´",
         ">", "< ", ";", ",", ":",
         ".", " "),
    '-',
    $string
);
return $string;
}
```

Puedes adaptarla a tus necesidades.

---

### ISO/IEC 646

Fuente http://www.kostis.net/charsets/iso646.irv.htm

```
ISO/IEC 646:1991 US ASCII
-------------------------

Hex   | Dec    | Chr  | Code  | ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000 Character Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------
20    | 32     |      | 32    | SPACE
21    | 33     | !    | 33    | EXCLAMATION MARK
22    | 34     | "    | 34    | QUOTATION MARK
23    | 35     | #    | 35    | NUMBER SIGN
24    | 36     | $    | 36    | DOLLAR SIGN
25    | 37     | %    | 37    | PERCENT SIGN
26    | 38     | &    | 38    | AMPERSAND
27    | 39     | '    | 39    | APOSTROPHE
28    | 40     | (    | 40    | LEFT PARENTHESIS
29    | 41     | )    | 41    | RIGHT PARENTHESIS
2A    | 42     | *    | 42    | ASTERISK
2B    | 43     | +    | 43    | PLUS SIGN
2C    | 44     | ,    | 44    | COMMA
2D    | 45     | -    | 45    | HYPHEN-MINUS
2E    | 46     | .    | 46    | FULL STOP
2F    | 47     | /    | 47    | SOLIDUS
30    | 48     | 0    | 48    | DIGIT ZERO
31    | 49     | 1    | 49    | DIGIT ONE
32    | 50     | 2    | 50    | DIGIT TWO
33    | 51     | 3    | 51    | DIGIT THREE
34    | 52     | 4    | 52    | DIGIT FOUR
35    | 53     | 5    | 53    | DIGIT FIVE
36    | 54     | 6    | 54    | DIGIT SIX
37    | 55     | 7    | 55    | DIGIT SEVEN
38    | 56     | 8    | 56    | DIGIT EIGHT
39    | 57     | 9    | 57    | DIGIT NINE
3A    | 58     | :    | 58    | COLON
3B    | 59     | ;    | 59    | SEMICOLON
3C    | 60     | <    | 60    | LESS-THAN SIGN
3D    | 61     | =    | 61    | EQUALS SIGN
3E    | 62     | >    | 62    | GREATER-THAN SIGN
3F    | 63     | ?    | 63    | QUESTION MARK
40    | 64     | @    | 64    | COMMERCIAL AT
41    | 65     | A    | 65    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
42    | 66     | B    | 66    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
43    | 67     | C    | 67    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
44    | 68     | D    | 68    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
45    | 69     | E    | 69    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
46    | 70     | F    | 70    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
47    | 71     | G    | 71    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
48    | 72     | H    | 72    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
49    | 73     | I    | 73    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
4A    | 74     | J    | 74    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
4B    | 75     | K    | 75    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
4C    | 76     | L    | 76    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
4D    | 77     | M    | 77    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
4E    | 78     | N    | 78    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
4F    | 79     | O    | 79    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
50    | 80     | P    | 80    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
51    | 81     | Q    | 81    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
52    | 82     | R    | 82    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
53    | 83     | S    | 83    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
54    | 84     | T    | 84    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
55    | 85     | U    | 85    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
56    | 86     | V    | 86    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
57    | 87     | W    | 87    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
58    | 88     | X    | 88    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
59    | 89     | Y    | 89    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
5A    | 90     | Z    | 90    | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
5B    | 91     | [    | 91    | LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
5C    | 92     | \    | 92    | REVERSE SOLIDUS
5D    | 93     | ]    | 93    | RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
5E    | 94     | ^    | 94    | CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
5F    | 95     | _    | 95    | LOW LINE
60    | 96     | `    | 96    | GRAVE ACCENT
61    | 97     | a    | 97    | LATIN SMALL LETTER A
62    | 98     | b    | 98    | LATIN SMALL LETTER B
63    | 99     | c    | 99    | LATIN SMALL LETTER C
64    | 100    | d    | 100   | LATIN SMALL LETTER D
65    | 101    | e    | 101   | LATIN SMALL LETTER E
66    | 102    | f    | 102   | LATIN SMALL LETTER F
67    | 103    | g    | 103   | LATIN SMALL LETTER G
68    | 104    | h    | 104   | LATIN SMALL LETTER H
69    | 105    | i    | 105   | LATIN SMALL LETTER I
6A    | 106    | j    | 106   | LATIN SMALL LETTER J
6B    | 107    | k    | 107   | LATIN SMALL LETTER K
6C    | 108    | l    | 108   | LATIN SMALL LETTER L
6D    | 109    | m    | 109   | LATIN SMALL LETTER M
6E    | 110    | n    | 110   | LATIN SMALL LETTER N
6F    | 111    | o    | 111   | LATIN SMALL LETTER O
70    | 112    | p    | 112   | LATIN SMALL LETTER P
71    | 113    | q    | 113   | LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
72    | 114    | r    | 114   | LATIN SMALL LETTER R
73    | 115    | s    | 115   | LATIN SMALL LETTER S
74    | 116    | t    | 116   | LATIN SMALL LETTER T
75    | 117    | u    | 117   | LATIN SMALL LETTER U
76    | 118    | v    | 118   | LATIN SMALL LETTER V
77    | 119    | w    | 119   | LATIN SMALL LETTER W
78    | 120    | x    | 120   | LATIN SMALL LETTER X
79    | 121    | y    | 121   | LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
7A    | 122    | z    | 122   | LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
7B    | 123    | {    | 123   | LEFT CURLY BRACKET
7C    | 124    | |    | 124   | VERTICAL LINE
7D    | 125    | }    | 125   | RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
7E    | 126    | ~    | 126   | TILDE
```

Comment: Muchas gracías por la información, el problema es que se debe emitir un certificado digital a través del Certificate Transparency de Google, y no acepta las url con diéresis, precisamente por no estar en esta codificación.
Muchas gracias nuevamente, veré a ver como solucionar este tema.